# Prove the the given matrix is totally unimodular

Tags: matrices, total-unimodularity, unimodular-matrices

I need to prove following matrix is totally unimodular:
[image: first matrix]

I know that I can delete the second, sixth and ninth columns, and then the sixth row, since each of them contains only one non-zero number, and I got to this matrix:

$\hskip 1.7 in$[image: second matrix]

I don't know how to continue from here: The matrix is too big tin order to use the definition, and in each row and column there are more then two non-zero numbers, so I can't use the row/column partition method.

How can I show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following result is mentioned in section 8 of [Fulkerson and Gross](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102995572) and also in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix#Common_totally_unimodular_matrices):

> The consecutive-ones property: if $A$ is (or can be permuted into) a 0-1 matrix in which for every row, the 1s appear consecutively, then $A$ is TU. (The same holds for columns since the transpose of a TU matrix is also TU.)